# Constructor question when building plugin / library

Tags: javascript

I’m tinkering around, trying to better understand how I’d go about building a custom jQuery plugin. I’ve never built my own library or plugin, so I’m kind of the bull in the china shop right now.

I have successfully managed to attach my library to the jquery object, however I’m not understanding a few things.

Within my library, I create a method on the prototype chain called checker. This works fine when I call it in my code. However, when I try instantiating the new object FunkyLib with some parameters, it says that FunkyLib is not a constructor, and I’m not sure why.
Here’s the code:

```
console.log('FuNkY Test');

(function ($, window, document, undefined) {

    function FunkyLib (options) {
        this.settings = options;
    }

    FunkyLib.prototype = { 
        checker: function() { alert('Purake'); }
    };

    $.fn.funky = new (FunkyLib);

}(jQuery, window, document));
```

If I were to try instantiating with some parameters with the constructor, I get an error in the console saying that FunkyLib is not a constructor.
For instance:

```
$.fn.funky = new (FunkyLib('Parameter'));
```

or

```
$.fn.funky = new (FunkyLib());
```

of even in the jquery call:

```
$('my-class').funky('param')
```

This works though:

```
$('my-class').funky.checker();
```

I’m pretty sure that my structure is just plain wrong. I have some material I’m reading, one of them being a tutorial on creating jQuery plugins. But I was hoping someone could give me a bit of 'to the point' advice on my errors here.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you add to the snippet so that it reproduces the issue?

Comment: @Steven B. Done, I hope that's what you meant :)

Comment: `$.fn.funky = new FunkyLib` will create an **object** consisting of your `settings` and `checker`, not a function. This is why `$.funky.checker()` works.

Comment: @TylerRoper  Okay, so could you explain the proper way to send parameters to the constructor method in this case? I guess it would have to be done prior to instantiating the object?

Comment: @silencedogood Can you explain the reasoning behind needing a constructor?  There may be another approach that would work more easily for your situation?

Comment: @TylerRoper Well, this is a generic example so the reason for the constructor is purely educational. However, I figured out the solution over the weekend. It's the way I'm invoking the object. I replaced this: $.fn.funky = new (FunkyLib(args));  with this: $.fn.funky = new FunkyLib(args);  and it worked like a charm. Guess the parenthesis are no good. Thanks for commenting!